# What does "Developer API" tag mean in Javadoc/Scaladoc?

Tags: apache-spark

Like here for example [HadoopRDD](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/rdd/HadoopRDD.html):

[image]

Can you still use it or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exact meaning of this annotation is explained in its [docstring](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.0.0/common/tags/src/main/java/org/apache/spark/annotation/DeveloperApi.java#L23-L25):

> A lower-level, unstable API intended for developers.
>
> Developer API's might change or be removed in minor versions of Spark.

So more or less "use at your own risk".

You can also check [Separate API annotation into two components: InterfaceAudience & InterfaceStability](http://apache-spark-developers-list.1001551.n3.nabble.com/discuss-separate-API-annotation-into-two-components-InterfaceAudience-amp-InterfaceStability-td17470.html)  on developers list for additional details and discussion.